# Paths between any two vertices in graph product

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

I considered the tensor product of two graphs, cycles $C_5$ and $C_7$, where I considered tensor product as $G = C_5 \times C_7$,

$V(C_5) = \{a,b,c,d,e\}$ and

$V(C_7) = \{1,2,3,4,5,6,7\}$.

According to the book "Handbook of Product Graphs", the distance between
any two vertices is

\begin{align}
d(x,y) = \min\{\text{$k$$|$each $G_i$ has an $x_i-y_i$ walk of length $k$ for $1\leq i\leq n$}\}.
\end{align}

Now I need to know that paths between the vertices $(a,1)$ and $(a,2)$ in $G$ of length $5$.

***My attempt:***   we have the $a-a$ and $1-2$  paths $a-b-c-d-e-a$ (or $a-e-d-c-b-a$) and $1-2$, resp in $C_5$ and $C_7$.

Thus, the paths of length 5 in $G$ are:

$$(a,1)(b,2)(c,1)(d,2)(e,1)(a,2)$$

and

$$(a,1)(e,2)(d,1)(c,2)(b,1)(a,2)$$.

Are these the only paths of length 5 in $G$. How to find other paths in $G$. Kindly help. Thanks.

Comment: There are more walks in $C_7$ to consider. How about 1-2-3-2-1-2 or 1-7-1-2-3-2, for example? There should be $\binom53$ of them in total.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Yeah, that is also an option like $1-7-1-7-1-2$. But how did you get ${5}\choose{3}$. I did not get this.

Comment: x @monalisa: Because we don't have time to go all the way around $C_7$, every length-5 walk from $1$ to $2$ must contain $3$ increments and $2$ decrements. The only freedom is to choose which of the $5$ steps are increments.